# Auto Suggest when press @ anywhere in the input field in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-autocomplete

I want auto suggestion for email adresses when I press @ anywhere in input field
example:
When i write some name like "John" and press @ then auto suggest like following:

```
john@gmail.com
john@yahoo.com
john@hotmail.com
```

Can anyone give a suggestion in JavaScript

Comment: -1 because you aren't asking a question, you're asking for us to write your code for you. You should do the following:
1) Show us that you've researched already
2) Tell us what you've tried
3) Provide and example of what you've got right now.

.... etc.

Comment: You're looking for an Autocomplete widget
http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: see example in http://jsfiddle.net/UKgD6/101/

Comment: my question same as this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6705999/jquery-autocomplete-to-start-on-pressing-character

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by overriding the keypress event in jQuery.ui.autocomplete as mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11430901/1671639).  Incase without overriding, you may have to do a lot as given by **@Brad's** [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16532412/1671639).

```
$(function () {
     var acList = ['gmail.com',
'yahoo.com',
'hotmail.com'
];
     var lastDot = -1;

     $("#tags").autocomplete({
         minLength: 0,
         source: function (request, response) {
             if (lastDot>=0) {
                 response($.ui.autocomplete.filter(
                 acList, extractLast(request.term.substring(lastDot+1))));          
             }
         },
         focus: function () {
             return false;
         },
         select: function (event, ui) {
             var terms = split(this.value);
             terms.pop();
             terms.push(ui.item.value);
             terms.push("");
             this.value = this.value.substr(0,lastDot+1);
             this.value += terms.join("");
             return false;
         }
     }).on("keypress", function (e) {
         var keys = [];
         keys.unshift(e.which);
         if (String.fromCharCode(keys[0]) == "@") {
             lastDot =  $("#tags").val().length;

         }
     });

     function split(val) {
         return val.split(/,\s*/);
     }

     function extractLast(term) {
         return split(term).pop();
     }
 });
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xHy6n/10/)

Comment: Thank you Praveen Jeganathan